# PostgreSQL: access to remote database

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, psql, su

I'm trying to access to remote database from local machine.

Under su I use the following command:

```
psql -h remotehost.ru -U user -d test_psql
```

But without success: I try '\l' and see database-list, which mounted on local machine.

In pg_hba.conf (at local and remote machines):

```
host  all  user  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

In postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: which error message do you get?

Comment: no error message

Comment: Can you telnet the remote machine? e.g telnet ip_of_remote_machine 5432
Also make sure that firewall is off on remote machine.

Comment: With telnet I have the same result